# Sdk version supported devices

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console

So I am not sure if this is the correct place for this, but I'm gonna give it a try. A few years ago I made a app for Android, but the project was deleted by a mistake. After now a few more years I decided to write it again.

I see this message:

```
Starting on August 31, 2023:

New apps must target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher; except for Wear OS apps, which must target a version between Android 11 (API level 30) and Android 13 (API level 33), inclusive.

App updates must target Android 13 or higher and adjust for behavioral changes in Android 13; except for Wear OS apps, which must target Android 11.
```

So in my build.gradle I did this:

```
android {
    namespace = "com.xxxxx.yyyyyy.droid"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.xxxxx.yyyyyy.droid"
        minSdk = 33
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 20
        versionName = "1.0.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Now when I upload it to Google Play Console, I see this:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lphhk.png)

Does this really means that if I now want to update my app, only 31 devices will be able to use my app, from totalt of 19 096 users?

Comment: No. It means that out of the totally supported devices (13,995), you are going to not be able to support 4,554 and you are going to gain support to 13 devices.

Comment: @tomerpacific Oh, ok! But as of my understanding, I have to to this, If I want to update the app now?

Comment: @tomerpacific Can you help me with this also please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77503907/android-studio-in-app-purchase-billingclient-problem

Answer (score 1):

As Play-Store message says

> New apps must target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher;

In your project you have to set API level 13 to both `minSdk` and `targetSdk`

```
minSdk = 33
targetSdk = 33
```

Downgrade your `minSdk` to your relevant older SDK version maybe,

```
minSdk = 21
```

It will solve your supported devices numbers.

The formula for `minSdk`, `targetSdk` and `compileSdk`

```
minSdkVersion <= targetSdkVersion <= compileSdkVersion
```

**minSdk** indicates that your app will support from this Android API level. Here in your code you set `minSdk` to latest higher one that's why it showing big difference with previously supported devices and Device no longer supported.

Comment: I am completly new to Android, only know iOS. But 33 is not the same as Android 33? How do I know what is what? What Android version is Sdk 21?

Comment: @Saland, Please visit this [Android API-level list with release notes](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platforms) you will get to know about Android API level as well.

Comment: @Saland, Another [API level with supported device numerics](https://apilevels.com/) for better understanding of various API level and versions.

Comment: But what about 'compileSdk = 34'? Does that matter in any case of compatibility?

Comment: Can you help me with this also please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77503907/android-studio-in-app-purchase-billingclient-problem